# DrawerLayout ways to get the NavigationView's width

Tags: android

I'm looking for ways to determine the [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html)'s width, especially **before** it has been opened?

This is my current implementation, it determines it's width when the [DrawerLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) opens:

```
@BindView(R.id.navDrawer) DrawerLayout mNavDrawer;
@BindView(R.id.navigation) NavigationView mNav;

private void setupNavDrawer() {
    mNavDrawer.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            final int navWidth = mNav.getWidth();
            // do something
        }
        @Override public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {}
        @Override public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {}
        @Override public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {}
    });
}
```